# get bluetooth address of self

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bluetooth

how to get bluetooth address of same device either through command line or program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems: First is that you never check for errors from any of the system calls.

The second is that the child process should *terminate* which yours doesn't. Instead your child process continues in the loop and call `accept` on the listening socket and so on, fighting with the parent process about connections. When the child process is done it should call `exit` to terminate.